# Parse curious json data with php

Tags: php, json, url

I tried everything now and can't get a value of this json:

```
[
{
place_id: "39915085",
licence: "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
osm_type: "node",
osm_id: "2986714415",
boundingbox: [
"48.6900961",
"48.6901961",
"9.1934061",
"9.1935061"
],
lat: "48.6901461",
lon: "9.1934561",
display_name: "Flughafen Stuttgart, 43, Flughafenstraße, Leinfelden-Echterdingen, Landkreis Esslingen, Regierungsbezirk Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, 70629, Deutschland",
class: "place",
type: "house",
importance: 0.101
}
]
```

I just want the "lat" value but cant get it with this for example:

```
$url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Stuttgart+Airport&format=json';

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$clima=json_decode($contents);
echo "test: ".$clima->lat;
```

I dont get it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/59788/calling-nominatim-with-file_get_contents

> PHP's file_get_contents() sends neither HTTP UserAgent nor Referer,
>   which violates the usage policy for the server. You can easily add
>   custom HTTP headers by creating an appropriate stream context like
>   that:
>
> // Create a stream $opts = array('http'=>array('header'=>"User-Agent:
>   StevesCleverAddressScript 3.7.6\r\n")); $context =
>   stream_context_create($opts);
>
> // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above $file =
>   file_get_contents('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/q=Rome',
>   false, $context); For more information see the PHP user manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cURL request to achieve this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Stuttgart+Airport&format=json'
));

echo json_decode(curl_exec($curl))->lat;
```

From the looks of it, `file_get_contents($url)` is stripping the `"` out of the parameters. The JSON response in your post is invalid therefor, `json_decode()` is returning null.

Comment: Hi KDOT, thanks for the quick answer. Your suggestion does not work for me :(

Comment: Hi, if you `var_dump()` the content of `$contents`, what do you get? I have just tried this on my site, I receive a **Access blocked** error. Are you possibly receiving this rather than the json? Possibly consider adding headers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the one you posted is not a JSON.

In JSON, the key is wrapped in double quotes.

```
{
     "jsonKey":"jsonValue",
}
```

Anyway, once you get the right JSON, since you get an array like this:

```
[
    {
        ....
        "lat":"48.6901461",
        ....
    }
]
```

You have to do this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$clima = json_decode($contents);
$latitude = $clima[0]->lat;
```